# Fetching array Mysql

Tags: mysql

O código retorna o erro 
 Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in uvas\checkout.php on line 262
é a mesma estrutura usada em outros blocos.
???

```
$c_email = $_SESSION['customer_email'];
$query  = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_email='$c_email";   
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $c_fname = $row['customer_fname'];
}
```

Comment: Poste a linha 262 que contém o `mysqli_fetch_array` o erro está lá

Comment: while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

Answer (score 1):

Antes do `mysqli_fetch_array` você deve executar sua sql com o [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php).
Passando sua conexão com o banco como parâmetro.

```
$c_email = $_SESSION['customer_email'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_email='$c_email";   
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $c_fname = $row['customer_fname'];
}
```

Pode verificar mais exemplos na documentação.
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Vdd.. Obrigado.

Comment: nao, nao eh vdd. valeu.

Comment: É verdade ou não é verdade ?

Comment: Se pela falta do query ok, mas nao justifica alguns blocos perderem a razao.